Error in the schema entry point webpack 5 multiple entry point
I was setting up a React project for a Chrome extension in which I needed more than one entry point and output in webpack, but I got an error when trying to configure more than one entry point in the webpack.config.js file. I have installed webpack 5.9, so according to the webpack documentation, this should work:
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    mode: "development",
    entry: {
        editor: './src/editor/editor.js',
        action: './src/action/action.js'
    }, // if we make this object just the first string "./src/editor/editor.js" the command npm build works
    output: {
        filename: '[name]/[name].js', // Simple output file for testing
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    },
    target: "web",
    devServer: {
        port: "3000",
        static: ["./build"],
        open: true,
        hot: true,
        liveReload: true,
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".ts"],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: "babel-loader",
            },
        ],
    },
};

When I run the command npm run build (webpack .), the console throws this error:
"[webpack-cli] Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

configuration.entry[0] should be a non-empty string.
-> A module that is loaded upon startup. Only the last one is exported."

what I am doing wrong?
my package.json file:
{
  "name": "task_mananger_ext",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/editor/editor.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server .",
    "build": "webpack ."
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.26.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.25.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
    "webpack": "^5.96.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1"
  }
}

i upload all in a repository at :https://github.com/FrancoDoce12/task_mananger_ext
Thanks for any help in advance!

The Solution was just adding on the package.json file those lines at the stript commands:
start":  "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"

Specifying the config script file
